# Docker: "too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: linux, docker, symlink, docker-layer, btcpay-server

i've been trying to install btcpay-server via my umbrel node. I ssh-ed into the server and pulled the docker image for btcpay-server.

On doing so, docker was unable to install the postgres layer and gave me this error:

```
ERROR: for postgres  failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebb37ae106ae0e6c4cdf1aa8c9175adcbd7f0c73e436e0772822ea4c6d8e1afa/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
ERROR: failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebb37ae106ae0e6c4cdf1aa8c9175adcbd7f0c73e436e0772822ea4c6d8e1afa/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

full logs:

```
Setting up data dir for app btcpay-server...
sending incremental file list

sent 160 bytes  received 16 bytes  117.33 bytes/sec
total size is 2,595  speedup is 14.74
Pulling images for app btcpay-server...
Pulling postgres  ... download complete
Pulling nbxplorer ... done
Pulling web       ... done

ERROR: for postgres  failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebb37ae106ae0e6c4cdf1aa8c9175adcbd7f0c73e436e0772822ea4c6d8e1afa/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
ERROR: failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebb37ae106ae0e6c4cdf1aa8c9175adcbd7f0c73e436e0772822ea4c6d8e1afa/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

I'm running all this on debian running on a raspberry pi 4.

docker version: **Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57**

The docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nbxplorer:
    image: nicolasdorier/nbxplorer:2.2.20@sha256:8f0e7f68513596e0a2555990d262169088a70204abe397bf18ba921f9b0608f3
    user: "1000:1000"
    restart: on-failure
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    volumes:
        - ${APP_DATA_DIR}/data/nbxplorer:/data
    environment:
        NBXPLORER_DATADIR: "/data"
        NBXPLORER_NETWORK: "$BITCOIN_NETWORK"
        NBXPLORER_PORT: 32838
        NBXPLORER_BIND: 0.0.0.0
        NBXPLORER_CHAINS: "btc"
        NBXPLORER_SIGNALFILEDIR: "/data"
        NBXPLORER_BTCRPCURL: "http://$BITCOIN_IP:$BITCOIN_RPC_PORT"
        NBXPLORER_BTCNODEENDPOINT: $BITCOIN_IP:$BITCOIN_P2P_PORT
        NBXPLORER_BTCRPCUSER: $BITCOIN_RPC_USER
        NBXPLORER_BTCRPCPASSWORD: $BITCOIN_RPC_PASS
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: $APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_NBXPLORER_IP

  web:
    image: btcpayserver/btcpayserver:1.4.2@sha256:17507f737d4398b7270f480468c088cd3f8dec9d3d5480a017645e3fd2351bb1
    user: "1000:1000"
    restart: on-failure
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    depends_on: [ nbxplorer, postgres ]
    entrypoint: [ "dotnet", "BTCPayServer.dll" ]
    ports:
        - "$APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_PORT:$APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_PORT"
    volumes:
        - ${APP_DATA_DIR}/data/btcpay:/data
        - ${APP_DATA_DIR}/data/nbxplorer:/data/.nbxplorer
        - ${LND_DATA_DIR}:/lnd:ro
    environment:
        HOME: "/data"
        BTCPAY_DATADIR: "/data"
        BTCPAY_PLUGINDIR: "/data/plugins"
        BTCPAY_DOCKERDEPLOYMENT: "false"
        BTCPAY_POSTGRES: "User ID=postgres;Host=$APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_DB_IP;Port=5432;Database=btcpayserver$BITCOIN_NETWORK"
        BTCPAY_NETWORK: "$BITCOIN_NETWORK"
        BTCPAY_BIND: 0.0.0.0:$APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_PORT
        BTCPAY_CHAINS: "btc"
        BTCPAY_BTCEXPLORERURL: "http://$APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_NBXPLORER_IP:32838"
        BTCPAY_BTCLIGHTNING: "type=lnd-rest;server=https://$LND_IP:$LND_REST_PORT/;macaroonfilepath=/lnd/data/chain/bitcoin/$BITCOIN_NETWORK/admin.macaroon;allowinsecure=true"
        BTCPAY_SOCKSENDPOINT: $TOR_PROXY_IP:$TOR_PROXY_PORT
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: $APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_IP

  postgres:
    image: btcpayserver/postgres:13.4-4@sha256:938574253f985b9ac7814329b576dc04a8fe6e330e214afcf3cd0bf4b41eceb8
    # This needs to run as root for migrations to succeed
    # user: "1000:1000"
    restart: on-failure
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
        - ${APP_DATA_DIR}/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: $APP_BTCPAY_SERVER_DB_IP
```